# failed to authenticate google translate in R

Tags: r, google-translate, google-translation-api

So I tried to use **gl_translate function** to 500,000 characters in Rstudio, which means I have to authenticate my google translate API. The problem is that I tried it like two months ago with my old google account and now I'm using the new one.

So when I tried to authenticate new **client_id** with my new google account, I got error message that my API hadn't been enabled yet, which I had enabled it. I restarted my Rstudio and now I got this error message:

```
020-01-22 19:01:24 -- Translating html: 147 characters - 
2020-01-22 19:01:24> Request Status Code: 403
Error: API returned: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

It is very frustrating because then I tried to enable the old google account and it requires me to put my credit card number, which is again I did and then now they asked me to wait several days.

Anyone can figure out what's problem with this?

here is my R code for authentication:

```
install.packages("googleAnalyticsR", dependencies = TRUE)
library(googleAnalyticsR)

install.packages("googleLanguageR")
library(googleLanguageR)

install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

library(tidyverse)

install.packages("googleAuthR")
library(googleAuthR)


client_id <- "107033903887214478396"
private_key <- "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\n9VaUDm7LCNTAskn2SR/o4Q==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

options(googleAuthR.client_id = client_id)
options(googleAuthR.client_secret =  private_key)

devtools::reload(pkg = devtools::inst("googleAnalyticsR"))
ga_auth()
```

in case you need to see what's my translate code like:

```
translate <- function(tibble) {

tibble <- tibble
count <- data.frame(nchar = 0, cumsum = 0) # create count file to stay within API limits

for (i in 1:nrow(tibble)) {

des <- pull(tibble[i,2]) # extract description as single character string

if (count$cumsum[nrow(count)] >= 80000) { # API limit check

  print("nearing 100000 character per 100 seconds limit, pausing for 100 seconds")

  Sys.sleep(100)

  count <- count[1,] # reset count file
}

if (grepl("^\\s*$", des) == TRUE) { # if description is only whitespace then skip

  trns <- tibble(translatedText = "", detectedSourceLanguage = "", text = "")

  } else { # else request translation from API

    trns <- gl_translate(des, target='en', format='html') # request in html format to anticipate html descriptions
}


tibble[i,3:4] <- trns[,1:2] # add to tibble

nchar = nchar(pull(tibble[i,2])) # count number of characters

req <- data.frame(nchar = nchar, cumsum = nchar + sum(count$nchar))

count <- rbind(count, req) # add to count file

if (nchar > 20000) { # addtional API request limit safeguard for large descriptions

  print("large description (>20,000), pausing to manage API limit")

  Sys.sleep(100)

  count <- count[1,] # reset count file
 }
}
return(tibble)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after 24 hours.

Apparently it is really easy. I just followed the step from this [link](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleLanguageR/index.html#installation).
But yesterday I make mistake because the json file I downloaded is the json file from **service client Id**, while I actually need the json file from **service account**.

Then I install the **googleLanguageR** package with this code:

```
remotes::install_github("ropensci/googleLanguageR")
library(googleLanguageR)
```

and then just set the file location of my download Google Project JSON file in a GL_AUTH argument like this:

```
gl_auth("G:/My Drive/0. Thesis/R-Script/ZakiServiceAccou***************kjadjib****.json")
```

and now I'm happy :)